# Why do I get this error when I run Pod install "[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile."

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift, react-native, pod-install

[image]

[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

[Xcodeproj] Consistency issue: no parent for object `RNPlaceholder.swift`: `SourcesBuildPhase`, `SourcesBuildPhase`

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/groupable_helper.rb:19:in `parent' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/build_file.rb:71:in` ascii_plist_annotation'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:296:in `block in to_ascii_plist' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:295:in` each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:295:in `to_ascii_plist' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:364:in` block in save'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/atomos-0.1.3/lib/atomos.rb:21:in `block in atomic_write' /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tempfile.rb:295:in` open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/atomos-0.1.3/lib/atomos.rb:17:in `atomic_write' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.19.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:363:in` save'
/Users/lwillia5/Documents/ebw/DJRainMobileApp/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb:136:in `block in exclude_architectures' /Users/lwillia5/Documents/ebw/DJRainMobileApp/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb:127:in` each'
/Users/lwillia5/Documents/ebw/DJRainMobileApp/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb:127:in `exclude_architectures' /Users/lwillia5/Documents/ebw/DJRainMobileApp/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb:145:in` react_native_post_install'
/Users/lwillia5/Documents/ebw/DJRainMobileApp/ios/Podfile:28:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:179:in` post_install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:897:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:885:in` block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:145:in `message' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:884:in` run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:329:in `block (2 levels) in create_and_save_projects' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pods_project_writer.rb:61:in` write!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:328:in `block in create_and_save_projects' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in` section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:307:in `create_and_save_projects' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:299:in` generate_pods_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:178:in `integrate' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:166:in` install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in` run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in` '

Pod file contents
[image]

Comment: can you show me pod file content

Comment: @ShivamParmar added above

Comment: You should not be installing gems into /Library/Ruby/Gems. Install your own ruby.

Comment: @matt ?? Can you please elaborate not sure I understand what I need to do

Comment: As I've explained here: https://www.biteinteractive.com/how-to-get-started-with-pods/